# Selenium loop script using too much ram, eventually crashing Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

I have a very large list of URLs I'm trying to **scrape**, I'm iterating over every URL using a for loop.

Eventually, in x element of the list, my Chrome window will crash ('Aw Snap!' error appears on the browser window). I don't have any idea to fix this issue.

I can't share my code, but is something like this:

very_large_url_list = [url1, url2, url3, url4...]

```
for x in very_large_url_list:
    driver.get(x)
    doStuff()
```

If I try to close the driver on every iteration, like this:

```
for x in very_large_url_list:
    driver.get(x)
    doStuff()
    driver.close()
```

I'd get an error stating that the session ID is invalid. If I don't close it, then a memory leakage will happen eventually and I wont be able to finish the iteration over the list. What can I do to fix this issue?

Please let me know if I haven't been clear enough so I can edit the question!

Comment: have you tried driver.navigate()? instead of get?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EDU67gY2 Here's the list, in the bottom there's the string format I used to get the links.

In my case, Webdriver doesn't seen to have an attribute named 'navigate'

Comment: @JainilPatel these is no such method `.navigate()` in python webdriver.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, here's the list along with the for loop I use for this question https://pastebin.com/6j5CxvrU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to close the driver on every iteration, shouldn't you be doing this?

```
for x in very_large_url_list:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(x)
    doStuff()
    driver.close()
```

Comment: driver is defined outside the for  loop. If I use driver.close inside the loop, on the next iteration I'd get the following error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id

Because the session ID is lost after the WebDriver is .close()

Comment: You legend. This fixes my issue, closing the window prevents memory leaks. Could you please explain to me why I can't .close() the WebDriver when its defined outside the for loop? I don't seem to catch the logic

Comment: Duh. If you close the WebDriver, then it's closed. You need to reopen it before you can use it again.

Comment: Of course, shouldn't it work even if its defined outside the for loop though. EDIT: Yup, I get it now. I swear I'm not stupid

Comment: or better yet, make the script data driven, run it in parallel and go X times faster.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue.  Can anyone (preferable the original poster of this question) confirm that the code above not only worked functionally, but solved the memory leakage issue?

Answer (score -1):

Do you know that we can open a URL without using any browser as well?  It is frequently asked interview question as well. Let’s learn it.

Let’s perform some steps first:

1. Open a browser.
2. Press F12.
3. Switch to Console tab.
4. Type `window.location='https://www.redbus.in'` and hit Enter key.

You will notice that redbus website is loaded.

This is the way of loading URL without using any methods like `get()` or `navigate()`. Above statement is called as JavaScript command. We will see JavaScript concepts later.

Comment: i reccommend you to use as much virtual memory availabe on your disk, change the virtual memory to full.

Comment: how much ram you have? i have 8 gb.

Comment: I'm sure it works fine just iterating over the list. My memory leakage occurs because of doStuff() inside my example. And I have to use doStuff(), that's the whole point of my script. I have 12 gb of RAM.

Comment: you are not providing dostuff(). ok try to write everything in file instead of storing in variable name, use AS MANY GLOBAL variables outside the for loop.

Comment: variables inside for loop are created many times and consume more space.

Comment: How do you think the driver loads the URL in the browser? This isn't doing anything novel that is going to solve OP's problem.